# add remove jquery in responsive layout

Tags: jquery

I have a responsive design in which i am using this code:

```
$('br').remove();
```

to remove the br when the browser windowsize is smaller than 
`767px`.
When I now open the browser in more than 767px the br's are there - that's fine. But when I resize the window to something beneath that size, they appear - (ok - that's what should happen) - but when I do a resize, the br's stay "removed"...
do I have to set another function with min-width and "add" the br again? Or what would be a propper way?
Thank you very much - as I am new to the ".add" ".remove" stuff with jquery

Comment: Please note that there is usually no need for Javascript for this kind of action, use `css media queries` instead.

Comment: thank you very much to all of you! As I am learning this stuff, I am very thankful for all your hints! AD

Comment: I finally did the @media solution and it's working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `hide()` and `show()` instead. Removing cannot be undone.

`$('br').hide();`

You can also consider going with CSS media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
   br {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: you can also do this by assigning a class to the <br> or <wbr> you want to suppress, which gives even more flecibility http://cssmojo.com/wbr-versus-br/

Answer (score 1):

`.remove` will remove element from `DOM` you can't get them back, you can hide them instead

```
$('br').hide();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use hide or show instead of add and remove. You want to listen on the window resize, check the viewport, and adjust based on pixels.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767){
          $('br').hide();
    }
    else{
          $('br').show();
    }
});
```